# Sending pictures from photobooth to phone via WeChat

Tags: wechat

My boss has charged me with the task of finding how to integrate WeChat into our photobooth's "Total Share" section.

Our photobooths work under windows and their software is a mix of Java and a PHP web API installed locally, that then connects to a web service.

The intention is to give the user the option to, when their picture is done, get a copy of it via WeChat (I guess that by introducing it's phone number)

Through my searches I've found a WeChat JS-SDK, but that seems to connect sites you are watching on your phone with your actual WeChat app so it doesn't work in my case.

The other source I have found is the Official Account Admin Platform, but I'm not really sure if this would allow me to do what I need. As far as I've seen, the Official Account can send messages in response to a trigger (that would work for me, send a message when the user clicks on the button), but it also seems to need that they "subscribe" (in a way) to the Official Account, and secondly I'm not sure how can this be automatized.

Especial mention:
I'm a junior developer, so API integration is a bridge I haven't crossed yet, and as such I'm utterly lost.

- **Is it possible to get the functionality I require? If so, what are the steps to do it?**

---

You don't need to make a fully fleshed tutorial to write an answer, just knowing in what direction should I go, and maybe some possible caveats that more experienced developers may be able to foresee, would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: Not at all. WeChat just did a whole revamp of how their api access works and it makes less sense to me than the earlier one...